How is the test function of Raviart-Thomas elements derived?
I know that the test function of RT0 elements (for 2D triangles) is
$$\mathbf\psi_j(\mathbf x) = \sigma_j \frac{E_j}{2|T|}(\mathbf x - \mathbf P _j),$$
which is an interpolation for the normal component of flux velocities at the interface of two adjacent triangles, if the Poisson equation for steady-state flow is solved by mixed finite element methods. $\sigma_j$ is the sign (-1 or + 1). $E_j$ is the length of the $j$th edge of triangles. $T$ is the area of triangles.
My question is:

How is this test function derived?
How can I derive the test function for other types of elements, such as 3D tetrahedrons (is it $\sigma_j \frac{|T_j|}{3V}(\mathbf x - \mathbf P _j)$ where $V$ is the volume of tetrahedrons)?


Have you looked at the literature on how these shape functions are derived? RT elements are widely used, and widely described in text books. In your case, you will be interested in reading up on the Piola transform, for example, to understand what the correct weight is going to be.

Some literature presented that the shape function on triangular reference elements is $\hat{\psi}_i = a + b \hat{x}$, and the shape function of source elements can be back-calculated by Piola transformation, such as $\psi = \frac{1}{\det{J}} J \hat{\psi}$. Other literature said that $\psi _ j = \frac{\mathbf x - \mathbf P_j}{d_j}$, where $d_j = \frac{2|T|}{E_j}$ is the normal distance from $P_j$ to $E_j$. Now, I think that $2|T| = \det{J}$. I cannot deduce if $J \hat{\psi}_j = E_j (\mathbf x - \mathbf P_j)$.

As described here https://defelement.com/elements/examples/triangle-raviart-thomas-lagrange-1.html, on the reference triangle
$$T:=\{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x\in[0,1],y\in[0,1-x] \}$$
the first degree RT basis functions are
$$\begin{aligned}
\psi_0:(x,y)\longmapsto & \begin{pmatrix}-x\\-y\end{pmatrix},\\
\psi_1:(x,y) \longmapsto& \begin{pmatrix}x-1\\y\end{pmatrix},\\
\psi_2:(x,y) \longmapsto& \begin{pmatrix}-x\\1-y\end{pmatrix}.
\end{aligned}$$
You were asking for a proof.
For this, define the RT functional
$$l_i(\psi_j):=\int_{F_i} \psi_j\cdot n_i.$$
Here I called $F_i$ the face (or in 2D: edge) $i$ and $n_i$ is the normal vector of this face/edge.
You can now check whether $\psi_i$ satisfy $l_i(\psi_j)=\delta_{ij}$. This is quite easy, i show you a few examples.
As on the website, lets say the face/edge

$F_2=\{(x,y)\in T: x\in[0,1], y=0\}$ is the face on the x-axis, and
$F_1=\{(x,y)\in T: x=0, y=[0,1]\}$ is the face on the y-axis.

Then:
$$\begin{aligned}
l_2(\psi_2)&= \int_{F_2} \psi_0\cdot n_2 = \int_0^1 \begin{pmatrix}-t\\1-0\end{pmatrix} \cdot\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix} dt = 1\\
l_1(\psi_2)&= \int_{F_1} \psi_0\cdot n_1 = \int_0^1  \begin{pmatrix}0\\1-t\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\end{pmatrix} dt = 0 \\
l_2(\psi_1)&= \int_{F_2} \psi_1\cdot n_2 = \int_0^1 \begin{pmatrix}-t\\0\end{pmatrix} \cdot\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix} dt = 0 \\
\text{etc.} &
\end{aligned}$$
You can check all other combinations.
Next: I claim that $\psi_1,\psi_2,\psi_3$ are linearly independent. You can check this by showing that the only real numbers $\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ that satisfy
$$\alpha \psi_1+\beta\psi_2+\gamma\psi_3=0$$
must all be zero: $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=0$. Let me know if you want me to do it explicitly.
Therefore, the span of the $\psi_i$ is indeed a vector space of dimension 3 and the $\psi_i$ are a basis of this space.
What is missing to obtain your expression is to transform the basis functions to a triangle (or quadrangle, or tetrahedron or whatever) of arbitrary shape - using an affine-linear element transform. This does not change the properties derived above (i.e. the nodal property, and the linear independence), so I will skip it.
I have discussed the local Finite Element space. To understand the global space, one has to study the existence of continuous trace-operators for normal components of $H(\text{div};\Omega)$-functions. To get a conforming global Finite Element space, we have to make sure that this normal-continuity gets preserved for each element interface. Let me know if you need more information about the global FEM space.
For other domain dimensions and other element types, I would still suggest to look at the website defelement, as it contains a lot of them. You can then verify yourself (using the method I layed out above) that the functions from the websites are in fact basis functions of the local FEM space, and that they have this "$\delta_{ij}$-property" - i.e. that they are the FEM basis functions you are looking for.

Thank you a lot. I do not understand is: for a reference triangle, when you calculate $\phi_0(\psi_0)$, why the normal vector $n_0 = [0, 1]^T$? As I see from the website, face 0 $F_0$ is the hypotenuse of the reference triangle, should $n_0$ be $1/\sqrt{2} \cdot [1, 1]^T$? Also, the integral is $\int_{F_0} = \int_0^1$, why the integration is from 0 to 1? I mean the length of $F_0$ is obviously not one.

Ok this is my fault: I used a different numbering than being presented on to the website.

I changed the notation: the functionals are now $l_i$ and the triangle faces are numbers as on the website.

And concerning the integral: when I write $\int_{F_i} f$ this is just a symbolic shorthand notation that means "I integrate the function $f$ over $F_i$". To actually compute this, we need to write down the expression of $f$ and evaluate it at $F_i$. So e.g. if you want to integrate $f(x,y)=2x+3y+x^2y+3$ along $F_2$, then in my notation I would write $\int_{F_2}f=\int_0^1 2t+3 dt$. The variable $t$ is just the integration parameter that I use to parametrize the face $F_2$. To make this more clear, I could have equivalently defined $F_2={(t,s)\in \mathbb{R}^2: t\in [0,1], s=0}$.

Thank you, @l'étudiant. I've seen many works using the local basis function $\hat{\psi}$ (as in your answer) with the Piola transformation to compute the stiffness matrix. I've also read some papers that use the global basis function $\psi_j = \frac{\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{P}_j}{d_j}$, where $\mathbf{P}_j$ is the $j$th node coordinate and $d_j$ is the normal distance to the $j$th face from node $j$. Can this global $\psi$ be derived from the local $\hat{\psi}$ via the Piola transformation? I tried but couldn't get it.

If you want, you can write the basis functions in your notation. E.g.: $\psi_2(x,y)=\frac{1}{d_2} [(x,y)-P_2]$, where $d_2=1$ and $P_2=(0,1)$, the upper node of the reference triangle. The Piola transform is a special kind of "affine-linear element transform" (see in my post above) that is divergence-preserving. We need this special transform, as a naive transform would change the direction of the normal vector and therefore the functionals $l_i$. Yes, the purpose of the Piola transform is to take a basis function on the reference element and transform it to a function on any physical element.

Keep in mind that the Piola transformation $P$ of a function $\hat f\in \hat V$ (the $\hat\cdot$ symbol means: "defined on the reference element") defined by $P:\hat V\to V$ with $f(F(\hat x))=(\text{det}F')^{-1} F'(\hat f(\hat x))$ depends on the map $F:\hat T\to T$ which transforms the reference triangle $\hat T$ into the physical triangle $T$.

Thank you for your helpful coomments! @l'étudiant.
